# Long equation causing content to overflow into footer

Tags: amsmath

I need to put the following equation (one equation number for all ) in two pages, instead of it to break into the next page it overflows into footer and the rest not showing at all. I have tried solutions from similar questions but not working for me. I am also including all the elements of the equation o that there will not be mix up.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,mathtools,amsthm,caption}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{\mathbb{V}ar}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{\mathbb{C}ov}
\DeclareMathOperator{\expect}{\mathbb{E}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
X_{t}-X_{t-1}&= (1-\alpha_{1}- \alpha_{2})X_{t}+ \alpha_{2}X_{t-1}+X_{t-   2}+\varepsilon_{t}\\
\rho &=\dfrac{\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k})}{\sqrt{\var(X_{t}).\var(X_{t+k})}}\\  
\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k}) &= \expect(X_{t}-\mu_{X_{t}})(X_{t+k}-\mu_{X_{t+k}})\\
&= \sum_{X_{t}} \sum_{X_{t+k}}(X_{t}-\mu_{X_{t}})(X_{t+k}-\mu_{X_{t+k}})p(X_{t},X_{t+k}) \text{ for  $(X_{t},X_{t+k})$ discrete}\\
&= \int\limits_{- \infty}^{ \infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (X- \mu_{X})(Y-\mu_{Y})f(x,y)dxdy \text{ for $(X,Y)$ continuous}\\ 
\text{Racall that }\\ 
\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k}) = \expect(X_{t}-\mu_{x_t})(X_{t+k}- \mu_{x_{t+k}})&=\expect(X_{t}(X_{t+k}-\mu_{x_{t+k}})-\mu_{x_t}(X_{t+k}-\mu_{x_{t+k}}))\\
&=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k}-\mu_{x_{t+k}}X_{t}-\mu_{x_t}X_{t+k}+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}})\\
&=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_{t+k}}\expect(X_{t})-\mu_{X}\expect(X_{t+k})+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}\\
&=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_{t+k}}\mu_{x_t}-    \mu_{X}\mu_{x_{t+k}}+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}\\
&=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-2\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}\\
\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k}) = \expect(X_{t}-\mu_{x_t})(X_{t+k}- \mu_{x_{t+k}})&=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}\\
\text{Recall also that }\\
\var(X_{t})&=\expect(X_{t}-\expect(X_{t})^2)\\
&=\expect(X_{t}-\expect(X_{t}))(X_{t}-\expect(X_{t}))\\
&=\expect(X_{t}^2-2X\expect(X_{t})+(\expect(X_{t})^2))\\
&=\expect(X_{t}^2)-\expect(2X_{t}\expect(X_{t}))+(\expect(X_{t}))^2\\
&=\expect(X_{t}^2)-2\expect(X_{t})\expect(X_{t})+(\expect(X_{t}))^2\\
&=\expect(X_{t}^2)-2(\expect(X_{t}))^2+(\expect(X_{t}))^2\\
&=\expect(X_{t}^2)-(\expect(X_{t}))^2\\
\var(X_{t})&=\sigma^2\\
\text{Similarly}\\
\var(X_{t+k})&=\expect(X_{t+k}-\expect(X_{t+k})^2)\\
&=\expect(X_{t+k}-\expect(X_{t+k}))(X_{t+k}-\expect(X_{t+k}))\\
&=\expect(X_{t+k}^2-2X\expect(X_{t+k})+(\expect(X_{t+k})^2))\\
&=\expect(X_{t+k}^2)-\expect(2X_{t+k}\expect(X_{t+k}))+(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2\\
&=\expect(X_{t+k}^2)-2\expect(X_{t+k})\expect(X_{t+k})+(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2\\
&=\expect(X_{t+k}^2)-2(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2+(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2\\
&=\expect(X_{t+k}^2)-(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2\\
\var(X_{t+k}) &=\sigma^2\\
\text{From }\rho_{t,t+k} &=\dfrac{\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k})} {\sqrt{\var(X_{t})\cdot\var(X_{t+k})}}\\  
\rho_{t,t+k} &=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t}}^2\cdot\sigma_{x_{t+k}}^2}}\\
&=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t}}^2}\cdot\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t+k}}^2}}\\
&=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}   {\sigma_{x_{t}}\cdot\sigma_{x_{t+k}}}\\
&=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}    {\sigma_{x}\cdot\sigma_x}\\
&=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sigma_x^2}\\
\label{eq3.5}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Please help.

Comment: in your MWE are missing some package in preamble or your definition of math operators ... please add them (and make MWE compilable)

Comment: `equation` environment can not be broken over pages. Delete them and instead `aligned` use `align` or `align*` (how you like to have numbered is not clear).

Comment: @Zarko I have edited it with necessary packages.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

Based on guessing and not knowing, which part of this huge derivation you like to number:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem,subcaption,tocbibind}
\usepackage{enumitem,subcaption}

\DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{cov}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\expect}{E}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
X_{t}-X_{t-1}
    &= (1-\alpha_{1}- \alpha_{2})X_{t}+ \alpha_{2}X_{t-1}+X_{t-   2}+\varepsilon_{t}\\
\rho &=\dfrac{\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k})}{\sqrt{\var(X_{t}).\var(X_{t+k})}}\\
\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k}) &= \expect(X_{t}-\mu_{X_{t}})(X_{t+k}-\mu_{X_{t+k}})\\
    &= \sum_{X_{t}} \sum_{X_{t+k}}(X_{t}-\mu_{X_{t}})(X_{t+k}-\mu_{X_{t+k}})p(X_{t},X_{t+k}) \text{ for  $(X_{t},X_{t+k})$ discrete}\\
    &= \int\limits_{- \infty}^{ \infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (X- \mu_{X})(Y-\mu_{Y})f(x,y)dxdy 
    \text{ for $(X,Y)$ continuous}
\intertext{Racall that}
\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k}) 
    & = \expect(X_{t}-\mu_{x_t})(X_{t+k}- \mu_{x_{t+k}})    \\
    &=\expect(X_{t}(X_{t+k}-\mu_{x_{t+k}})-\mu_{x_t}(X_{t+k}-\mu_{x_{t+k}}))\\
    &=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k}-\mu_{x_{t+k}}X_{t}-\mu_{x_t}X_{t+k}+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}})\\
    &=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_{t+k}}\expect(X_{t})-\mu_{X}\expect(X_{t+k})+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}\\
    &=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_{t+k}}\mu_{x_t}-    \mu_{X}\mu_{x_{t+k}}+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}\\
    &=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-2\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}\\
\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k}) 
    &= \expect(X_{t}-\mu_{x_t})(X_{t+k}- \mu_{x_{t+k}})\\
    &=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}
\intertext{Recall also that }
\var(X_{t})
    &=\expect(X_{t}-\expect(X_{t})^2)\\
    &=\expect(X_{t}-\expect(X_{t}))(X_{t}-\expect(X_{t}))\\
    &=\expect(X_{t}^2-2X\expect(X_{t})+(\expect(X_{t})^2))\\
    &=\expect(X_{t}^2)-\expect(2X_{t}\expect(X_{t}))+(\expect(X_{t}))^2\\
    &=\expect(X_{t}^2)-2\expect(X_{t})\expect(X_{t})+(\expect(X_{t}))^2\\
    &=\expect(X_{t}^2)-2(\expect(X_{t}))^2+(\expect(X_{t}))^2\\
    &=\expect(X_{t}^2)-(\expect(X_{t}))^2\\
\var(X_{t})
    &=\sigma^2
\intertext{Similarly}
\var(X_{t+k})
    &=\expect(X_{t+k}-\expect(X_{t+k})^2)\\
    &=\expect(X_{t+k}-\expect(X_{t+k}))(X_{t+k}-\expect(X_{t+k}))\\
    &=\expect(X_{t+k}^2-2X\expect(X_{t+k})+(\expect(X_{t+k})^2))\\
    &=\expect(X_{t+k}^2)-\expect(2X_{t+k}\expect(X_{t+k}))+(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2\\
    &=\expect(X_{t+k}^2)-2\expect(X_{t+k})\expect(X_{t+k})+(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2\\
    &=\expect(X_{t+k}^2)-2(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2+(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2\\
    &=\expect(X_{t+k}^2)-(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2\\
\var(X_{t+k}) 
    &=\sigma^2
\intertext{From}
\rho_{t,t+k} 
    &=\dfrac{\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k})} {\sqrt{\var(X_{t})\cdot\var(X_{t+k})}}\\
\rho_{t,t+k}
    &=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t}}^2\cdot\sigma_{x_{t+k}}^2}}\\
    &=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t}}^2}\cdot\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t+k}}^2}}\\
    &=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}   {\sigma_{x_{t}}\cdot\sigma_{x_{t+k}}}\\
    &=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}    {\sigma_{x}\cdot\sigma_x}\\
    &=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sigma_x^2}
\label{eq3.5}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum**

Some (of-topic) comments:

- for variance, covariance and expectation are usually used symbols Var, Cov and E, ie ther definitons should be:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{Cov}
\DeclareMathOperator{\expect}{E}
```

- to have one number for equation, which is actually set blocks of equations separated by text and spread over two pages, is fragile and may lead to conclusion that the number is belong to particular part of your equation. As solution can be use of sub equation numbering like

```
\begin{subequations}\label{eq3.5}
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}\label{eq3.5a}
...
    \end{split}
\intertext{Racall that}
    \begin{split}\label{eq3.5b}
...
    \end{split}
\intertext{Recall also that}
    \begin{split}\label{eq3.5c}
...
    \end{split}
\intertext{Similarly}
    \begin{split}\label{eq3.5d}
...
    \end{split}
\intertext{From}
    \begin{split}\label{eq3.5e}
...
    \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

which gives (shown is only last three blocks of equations):

[image]

- using above equation numbering allows to broke your "equation" into simple sequence of five equations with common main number. In this case text in `\intertext{...}` is converted to ordinary text in your document.
- reconsider, if it is really necessary that each step of derivation had to be in new line. With merging of some steps into one line "equation" will become shorter. For example

```
\intertext{From}
    \begin{split}\label{eq3.5e}
\rho_{t,t+k} 
    &=\dfrac{\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k})} {\sqrt{\var(X_{t})\cdot\var(X_{t+k})}}
     =\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t}}^2\cdot\sigma_{x_{t+k}}^2}}\\
    &=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t}}^2}\cdot\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t+k}}^2}}
     =\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}   {\sigma_{x_{t}}\cdot\sigma_{x_{t+k}}}
     =\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}    {\sigma_{x}\cdot\sigma_x}\\
\rho_{t,t+k}
    &=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sigma_x^2}
    \end{split}
```

which gives

[image]

- the first block of your "equation" is probably beter to write as

```
    \begin{split}\label{eq3.5a}
X_{t}-X_{t-1}
    &= (1-\alpha_{1}- \alpha_{2})X_{t}+ \alpha_{2}X_{t-1}+X_{t-   2}+\varepsilon_{t}\\
\rho&=\dfrac{\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k})}{\sqrt{\var(X_{t}).\var(X_{t+k})}}\\
\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k}) 
    &= \expect(X_{t}-\mu_{X_{t}})(X_{t+k}-\mu_{X_{t+k}})\\
    &=  \begin{dcases}
    \sum_{X_{t}}\sum_{X_{t+k}}(X_{t}-\mu_{X_{t}})(X_{t+k}-\mu_{X_{t+k}})p(X_{t},X_{t+k}) 
        &   \text{ for  $(X_{t},X_{t+k})$ discrete}\\
    \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (X - \mu_{X})(Y-\mu_{Y})f(x,y)dxdy 
        &   \text{ for $(X,Y)$ continuous}
        \end{dcases}
    \end{split}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: I want one equation number for all.

Comment: and where the equation number should be? on which page? at which equation line?

Comment: @economia, any news? See addendum to my answer, maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope autobreak.sty may help you, here is the code:

```
    \documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,mathtools,amsthm,caption}
\usepackage{autobreak}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{\mathbb{V}ar}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{\mathbb{C}ov}
\DeclareMathOperator{\expect}{\mathbb{E}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\everyafterautobreak{\quad}
\begin{autobreak}
X_{t}-X_{t-1}= (1-\alpha_{1}- \alpha_{2})X_{t}+ \alpha_{2}X_{t-1}+X_{t- 2}+\varepsilon_{t} \rho
=\dfrac{\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k})}{\sqrt{\var(X_{t}).\var(X_{t+k})}} \cov(X_{t},X_{t+k})
= \expect(X_{t}-\mu_{X_{t}})(X_{t+k}-\mu_{X_{t+k}})
= \sum_{X_{t}} \sum_{X_{t+k}}(X_{t}-\mu_{X_{t}})(X_{t+k}-\mu_{X_{t+k}})p(X_{t},X_{t+k})
\text{ for $(X_{t},X_{t+k})$ discrete} = \int\limits_{- \infty}^{ \infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (X- \mu_{X})(Y-\mu_{Y})f(x,y)dxdy
\text{ for $(X,Y)$ continuous} \text{Racall that } \cov(X_{t},X_{t+k})
= \expect(X_{t}-\mu_{x_t})(X_{t+k}- \mu_{x_{t+k}})=\expect(X_{t}(X_{t+k}
-\mu_{x_{t+k}})-\mu_{x_t}(X_{t+k}-\mu_{x_{t+k}}))
=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k}-\mu_{x_{t+k}}X_{t}-\mu_{x_t}X_{t+k}+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}})
=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_{t+k}}\expect(X_{t})-\mu_{X}\expect(X_{t+k})+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}
=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_{t+k}}\mu_{x_t}- \mu_{X}\mu_{x_{t+k}}+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}
=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-2\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}+\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}} \cov(X_{t},X_{t+k})
= \expect(X_{t}-\mu_{x_t})(X_{t+k}- \mu_{x_{t+k}})=\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}
\text{Recall also that } \var(X_{t})=\expect(X_{t}-\expect(X_{t})^2)
=\expect(X_{t}-\expect(X_{t}))(X_{t}-\expect(X_{t})) =\expect(X_{t}^2-2X\expect(X_{t})
+(\expect(X_{t})^2)) =\expect(X_{t}^2)-\expect(2X_{t}\expect(X_{t}))+(\expect(X_{t}))^2
=\expect(X_{t}^2)-2\expect(X_{t})\expect(X_{t})+(\expect(X_{t}))^2
=\expect(X_{t}^2)-2(\expect(X_{t}))^2+(\expect(X_{t}))^2 =\expect(X_{t}^2)-(\expect(X_{t}))^2 \var(X_{t})
=\sigma^2 \text{Similarly} \var(X_{t+k})=\expect(X_{t+k}-\expect(X_{t+k})^2)
=\expect(X_{t+k}-\expect(X_{t+k}))(X_{t+k}-\expect(X_{t+k})) =\expect(X_{t+k}^2-2X
\expect(X_{t+k})+(\expect(X_{t+k})^2)) =\expect(X_{t+k}^2)-\expect(2X_{t+k}\expect(X_{t+k}))+(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2
=\expect(X_{t+k}^2)-2\expect(X_{t+k})\expect(X_{t+k})+(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2 =\expect(X_{t+k}^2)
-2(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2+(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2 =\expect(X_{t+k}^2)-(\expect(X_{t+k}))^2 \var(X_{t+k})
=\sigma^2 \text{From }\rho_{t,t+k} =\dfrac{\cov(X_{t},X_{t+k})} {\sqrt{\var(X_{t})\cdot\var(X_{t+k})}} \rho_{t,t+k}
=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t}}^2\cdot\sigma_{x_{t+k}}^2}}
=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t}}^2}\cdot\sqrt{\sigma_{x_{t+k}}^2}}
=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}} {\sigma_{x_{t}}\cdot\sigma_{x_{t+k}}}
=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}} {\sigma_{x}\cdot\sigma_x}
=\dfrac{\expect(X_{t}X_{t+k})-\mu_{x_t}\mu_{x_{t+k}}}{\sigma_x^2}
\end{autobreak}\label{eq3.5}
\end{align}
```

Comment: may it is difference in text editor, I got badbox error. I use textstudio

Comment: I'm using Epsilon as my text editor..